# Join запрос с json

Tags: php

У меня есть таблица *cars_krep* с колонкой id, и таблица *products* с колонкой id_cars_krep (в ней id креплений хранятся в виде {"id_krep":[1,2,4]} ). Можно ли как то соединить эти колонки, как в примере ?

```
$data = $db->getAll('SELECT products.*, cars_krep.* 
FROM cars_krep 
LEFT JOIN products 
on cars_krep.id = products.id_cars_krep');
```

Comment: Это вообще-то вопрос о чистом SQL. Так что укажите точно СУБД, включая версию, выложите CREATE TABLE обеих таблиц, INSERT INTO с примером данных (3-5 строк), требуемый ответ для этих данных и пояснения. И добавьте к вопросу тег СУБД. *Можно ли как то соединить эти колонки* Конечно, можно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean You use MySQL DB. So you can use function JSON_CONTAINS in JOIN statement in next way:

Предположим, вы используете БД MySQL. Таким образом, вы можете использовать функцию JSON_CONTAINS в операторе JOIN следующим образом:

```
<?php
$sql = "select *
    from cars_krep
    join products on JSON_CONTAINS(id_cars_krep, JSON_ARRAY(cars_krep.id), '$.id_krep');";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($rows);
```

[PHP MySQL online test](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/cbdb083053098bc1529bd6630d1268c1/php/php8/56137891ea1eeca08758904fc8388e80/)